# Having issues selecting a Schema in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

It will not let me create the table. It claims that there is a syntax error by CREATE but when I click the more detailed information section it says that it has something to do with the SET keyword. I have had this issue consistently after running the software on two different machines and uninstalling and reinstalling about 4 times.

I currently have the following code in pgAdmin 4 on Windows

```
SET search_path = "laboratories"

CREATE TABLE Product()
```

Comment: Are you missing `;` between the two lines?

Comment: It gives me the following error when I do that. ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in

Comment: Does the schema `laboratories` exist? Do `select nspname from pg_namespace;` to confirm.

Comment: Advise: Always use a schema qualification, to avoid issues like this and unexpected search paths. `CREATE TABLE laboratories.product();`